# CSRF protection with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, csrf

I'm unable to find Symfony documentation to activate CSRF protection in existent forms (with no protection).

I've set the csrf_protection with a token and so on, but forms are failing and I guess something is needed to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Check that:

- There's an entry for it in settings.yml
- The CSRF token is rendered with the form in the template
- CSRF token is not disabled inside the form class (or its parents)

... that should work.

Answer (score 0):

try rendering it manually in the template, it should be on by default. `{{ form_widget(formName._token) }}`

if this doesnt work try adding it to the form method `setDefaultOptions`

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
        'csrf_protection' => true
    ]);
```